# Manually modifying ArcGIS Server Geoprocessing Parameters Data Type?

Tags: arcgis-server, python-toolbox, geoprocessing-service

In ArcGIS 10.5, when I publish a Python Toolbox result as service, the parameters such as `GPRasterDataLayer` become `GPString` if these parameters are unfilled when running the toolbox on Desktop. This causes errors when using these `GPString` parameters as they are supposed to be `GPRasterDataLayer`. Is there any way to go to the server `arcgisserver\directories` or any folder and modify the data types?

Comment: Can you provide a test.pyt that contains just enough code to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: This applies to all toolboxes I tried. If you try any toolbox you have, you will face the same problem.

Comment: Modifying a deployed service by hacking the folder contents in the config store can't be a supported methodology. I doubt Tech Support would go there, though they might have a different solution.

Comment: @Vince true but there is no option to modify parameters from an interface. Absence of this is the reason why modifying the the config is needed.

Comment: No, modifying the config is not an option. Publishing from an execution with all the parameters is a better solution.

Comment: @Vince I tried that but it fails to publish in that case. What is the maximum number of parameters accepted?

Comment: I don't think I've exceeded 12 parameters on a GP service, but I only used `GPString`, and validated appropriately (using ArcObjects Java). I really do think this is an XY Problem, and that you should focus on a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you're trying to fix a problem by addressing the unexpected end behavior, when in fact you should be trying to fix the problem causing the issue. You should not try to modify the parameters from the tbx/pyt inside the `arcgisinput` directory. Actually, you can't. This information is baked into the binary files inside the service. (You could technically hack the code in the .py or .pyt, but you can't 'hack' the service as asked in your question)

I'm not really sure why you're seeing a `GPRasterDataLayer` parameter get turned into a `GPString`, but your comment on this only happens when you don't supply an input. The seemingly obvious answer here is to provide the tool with a raster dataset when you run it, before publishing. The result from your execution will know and honor the `GPRaster` input when creating the service. Running the tool on desktop in the same way someone would use it as a service, prior to publishing, sets the service up to be well defined and avoids these problems of unexpected executions/parameter types/etc.

Thinking about your situation, you're talking GPRaster**Layer** -- does this mean you want a hardcoded set of layers the user will choose from at execution time? Or do you want to allow the user to send a raster of their own to the GP Service? If the later, you'll need to change your input parameter type from Layer to **Dataset**. This scenario is all about having a good, well defined tool, so when creating a service you get that same experience.

Comment: If it is in a binary file, then there is no hope for me. Regarding `GPRasterLayer` vs `Dataset`. I am using already published image services. There is an option to Upload, even though not working. When it works, I want to publish the uploaded image as image service so that users can see the map of course ArcGIS Rest API refused to work too so I might go to the Dataset Route. Thank you for the input!

Comment: Why doesn't ArcGIS server creates the same parameter data type as provided in python?

Comment: Geoprocessing Services only support a sub-set (10-12) of the full parameter list. The reasons don't really matter, because it is what it is and you need to work within the list of supported parameters. The thing to note, if a parameter type is NOT supported, it is either mapped to CONSTANT (hardcoded) or STRING. This might be what you're seeing.

Comment: All of that said, you can use image service layers **in** a gp service (not as a true parameter, but referenced inside the code) and you can use raster layers and raster datasets. So I'm not entirely sure where you're running into problems.

Comment: The tool I failed to publish has about 60 parameters.

Comment: The number of parameters doesn't matter. You could have 1 million (although the more you have, the harder the tool is to use, and slower it works). The 10-12 value I'm referring to is for parameter types. (gpstring, gpboolean, gpfeatureset, etc)